# Displaying Images Correctly

Tags: java

So, I've been working on several smaller game project in past few months, and I've got the hang of game dev in java. Now I'm trying to optimize game performance. Is it ok to simply use `g.drawImage();`to display sprites and other images?

Note that I'm trying not to use any external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable to use g.drawImage(); to render your bitmaps.

Most of the optimization you'll be doing is cutting down on the number of times you call that method, rather than using some other method entirely.  For example, you might only clear the parts of the background that have changed ("dirty rectangles") and draw the changed parts over top of it, or you might construct your scene by rendering tiles/layers to a secondary bitmap/buffer and then just draw that bitmap to the screen rather than reconstruct the scene.  (FWIW, when I worked on professional projects for pre-smartphone era devices a lot of these didn't work so good so it was pointless to get fancy).

Comment: Thank you very much, this very well answers my question :)